# Tumblr API jQuery random image

Tags: jquery, random, tumblr

I want a random image as background in a div element.
I use the tumblr API to get images from tumblr.
The following code works but gets only the last image that is found, how can I get a random image from the array?

[Working Example: jsfiddle.net/StevendeJong/9pzhh9z5/2](http://jsfiddle.net/StevendeJong/9pzhh9z5/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    var link = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/www.unsplash.com/posts?";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url : link,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            api_key: "ClAjag2DrKwJhbFY1aAAwqBUxEFBEOBwc7AzMwXlcaNlp3gZte"
        }
    }).done(function( data ) {

        $.each(data.response.posts, function(){

            var _photos = this.photos;

            $.each(_photos, function(){
                $('.background').css({
                    "background-image": "url(" + this.original_size.url + ")"
                });
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this:

You are getting final as you are iterating through the list in the each..

See updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9pzhh9z5/3/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var link = "http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/www.unsplash.com/posts?";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: link,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {
            api_key: "ClAjag2DrKwJhbFY1aAAwqBUxEFBEOBwc7AzMwXlcaNlp3gZte"
        }
    }).done(function (data) {

        var url = $.rand(data.response.posts);
        url = url.photos[0].original_size.url;
        console.log(url);
        console.log($.rand(data.response.posts));
        $('DIV.background').css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');;

        });
    });
```

I am using this function to randomise the array:

```
//random function. 
(function ($) {
            $.rand = function (arg) {
                if ($.isArray(arg)) {
                    return arg[$.rand(arg.length)];
                } else if (typeof arg == "number") {
                    return Math.floor(Math.random() * arg);
                }
            };
        })(jQuery);
```

**UPDATE**
To get the 1280 size if available you can add this check:

```
 var url = $.rand(data.response.posts);
 var alt = url.photos[0].alt_sizes[0];
 url = alt.width == 1280 ? alt.url : url.photos[0].original_size.url;
```

UPDATED FIDDLE: 
http://jsfiddle.net/9pzhh9z5/5/

Comment: Also - you should consider using the alternative photo sizes in that array - some of the origonal size photos that are returned are huge, and would be a bit slow to load into the background.

Comment: If you want I can modify the fiddle so that it uses the smaller sized images (check your console log).

Comment: This works nice, how can I always get the 1280 size from the `alt sizes` and if this size is not available the original_size?

Comment: Hi @StevendeJong - I have updated answer + fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9pzhh9z5/5/ if you want 1280 or higher, change the `==` to `>`

Answer (score 1):

If each post only has one photo, then you could select one with something like:

```
var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.response.posts.length);
var post = data.response.posts[r];
```

And then set you background:

```
$('.background').css({
    "background-image": "url(" + post.photos[0].original_size.url + ")"
});
```

No `$.each` loops required. If each post can contain multiple photos, then it isn't difficult to also select a random photo from a random post.

http://jsfiddle.net/9pzhh9z5/4/

Comment: @StevendeJong: What "doesn't work"? It [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/9pzhh9z5/4/)